# Installation bug

Tags: boot, system-installation, 16.10

What should I do to install Ubuntu on my laptop?

It's an MSI laptop with a i7-6700hq processor, and shows this screen when booted:

[image: photo of screen showing some boot messages]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Is your installation done? If not then for how much time your system shows this? Have you waited for it to complete?

Comment: This video helped me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdLe3Kao2Ok after installation i had to change in grub quiet splash  to nomodeset too.